# Modify SQL code and queries in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help and thank you very much!

How do I get this result?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EedXW.png

This is my current result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydzn0.png

Code:

```
WITH shiftHours AS 
(
    SELECT 
        RowID,
        y.EMPLOYEENAME AS EMPLOYEENAME,
        -- flatten the first hour to remove the minutes and get the initial current hour
        DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ShiftA_Start), 0) AS currentHour,
        ShiftA_Start,
        ShiftA_End,
        DATEPART(hour, ShiftA_Start) AS hourOrdinal,
        -- determine how much of the first hour is applicable. if it is minute 0 then the whole hour counts
        CAST(CASE 
            WHEN DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ShiftA_Start), 0) = DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ShiftA_End), 0) THEN DATEDIFF(minute, ShiftA_Start, ShiftA_End) / 60.0
           WHEN DATEPART(minute, ShiftA_Start) = 0 THEN 1.0
           ELSE (60 - DATEPART(minute, ShiftA_Start)) / 60.0
        END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS hourValue
    FROM 
        (-- use a ROW_NUMBER() to generate row IDs for the shifts to ensure each row is unique once it gets to the pivot
         SELECT 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ShiftA_Start, ShiftA_End) AS RowID,
             EMPLOYEENAME,
             ShiftA_Start,
             ShiftA_End
         FROM 
             (-- this is where the data gets pulled from the source table and where the data types are converted from string to DATETIME
              SELECT 
                  EMPLOYEENAME,
                  CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_start, 17), 103) AS ShiftA_Start,
                  CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_start, 17), 103) AS ShiftA_end,
                  CAST(CASE 
                          WHEN DATEPART (day, [ShiftA_Start]) = DATEPART (day, [SHIFTA_END])
                              THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_end, 17), 103) 
                          WHEN DATEPART (hour, [ShiftA_Start]) = DATEPART (hour, [SHIFTA_END])
                              THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_end, 17), 103)  + '23:59:00.000' END AS VARCHAR(30)) AS S_END
               FROM
                   [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TMS_PEOPLE]
               WHERE
                   CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_START, 17), 103) IS NOT NULL 
                   AND CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_END, 17), 103) IS NOT NULL
                   AND CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_START, 17), 103) != CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_END, 17), 103)
                   AND CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_START, 17), 103) != '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                   AND CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_END, 17), 103) != '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                   --AND  CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_start, 17), 103) = '2016-01-24 14:09:00.000'
                   AND EMPLOYEENAME = 'MUHAMMAD BIN PARMIN'

                   -- this is also where you would add any filtering from the source table such as date ranges
             ) x
) AS y

UNION ALL

SELECT RowID,
EMPLOYEENAME,
    -- add an hour to the currentHour each time the recursive CTE is called
    DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour) AS currentHour,
    ShiftA_Start,
    ShiftA_End,
    DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour)) AS hourOrdinal,
    CAST(CASE
        -- when this is the last time period determine the amount of the hour that is applicable
        WHEN DATEADD(hour, 2, currentHour) > ShiftA_End THEN DATEPART(minute, ShiftA_End) / 60.0
        ELSE 1
    END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS hourValue
from shiftHours

-- contine recursion until the next hour is after the ShiftEnd
WHERE DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour) < ShiftA_End
)
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT RowID,
EMPLOYEENAME,
    ShiftA_Start,
    ShiftA_End,
    hourValue,
    hourOrdinal
from shiftHours

) AS t
PIVOT (
SUM(hourValue)
FOR hourOrdinal IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])
) AS pvt
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

JKQDJKBDJAJSDudkbsjkdbjkBhsjkdbnbjasadbjbdjajdbka dhajdkbobKJBDJBAJBDO

Comment: Your query seems rather complex for the question, and just exactly what is the question? Is the value you want, 23:59:00 on the day of the shift end? What is the source data you've got for the row displayed?

Comment: @Vannessa, I need to learn how to make someone else write software for me for free, without even saying so much as a thank you to those people. Can you help?

Comment: @Vanessa I suggest you make an effort to close off the other 7 questions that you have asked along these same lines. If you made an effort to understand and complete those other question you might find you could solve your recurring shift problem.

Comment: @Alex sorry I mistaken your sentence, are you saying Im rude ?

Comment: @JohnBingham I want to change all the SHIFTA_END timing to 23:59:00.000

Comment: @Vannessa, Nick.McDermaid has rephrased my tongue-in-cheek comment into plain English. I am saying that you are abusing this website. You ask people to write your software for you bit-by-bit. You never accept their answers. You never say so much as thanks. This website is designed to help people to learn and not to find other people to do your work.

Comment: @Alex Wow. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Alex This platform is meant for asking and learning as you suggested and claimed. This site is not a place for you to humiliate and teach people what should they do. You didn't help in anyway either. This place is for helping and learning. THANK YOU for your cooperation.

Comment: @Vanessa I think it's likely that if you make no effort to complete prior questions then people are unlikely to continue contributing to new questions.

Comment: @Alex, Nick.McDermaid - thanks for your comments on this post, having read them I'm not going to do anything further with this question.

Answer (score 1):

In your inner query you have this line

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_start, 17), 103) AS ShiftA_end,
```

should you not use the end of the shift instead?